# Command Line MySQL Script

Tags: php, mysql, perl, command-line, command-line-arguments

Been trying to figure out a few ways around this, and back to square 1.

My hosting package only apparently has supporting software for PHP, SendMail and Perl from the command line - but I need to figure out the best way to run an SQL script, whether it be from the command line as a MySQL script (if that's possible), or within a PHP or Perl script.

I have tried the following script within a PHP script, but the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE prevents it from running properly, so I'm stumped as to an easier solution... but at this stage I'll take any!

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'xxxx-xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxx-xxxxxxx');
mysqli_query($con, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/datafeed.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE product_feed FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS");
mysqli_close($con);
```

Command lines are very new to me, and to be honest I only need to know as it's how I construct a schedule task/cron job for an update script.

Can anyone help me out

Comment: `LOAD DATA LOCAL` is intended for use from a remote client where `LOCAL` refers to the client. If you'e executing this on the server then drop the `LOCAL` keyword and make sure the MySQL user has appropriate access to the source directory. Also, I don't believe MySQL supports reading the file from a URL.

Comment: If I drop LOCAL, MySQL tells me I don't have permission to access the database. I have checked this with my host provider and this is correct, and they don't let custs grant permission or privileges for MySQL - hence, I'm 'settling' for the LOCAL option, though it's not my preference.

Comment: From the MySQL manual: _If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server._ See the reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html). What you're doing simply won't work.

Comment: You have marked my answer as accepted, but I'm not at all sure that I have given you enough information. You say, *“Command lines are very new to me,”* and I expected further questions to clarify what I had written. Command lines are mostly just a way of running a program and passing parameters to it in text form. It is similar to a windowed application, but the latter generally allows you specify several *things to do* in a single run of the program. A command line will usually start a program, which then just what your command specified and exits.

Comment: You presumably have access to `mysqli` on the server system? I suggest that you simply use that once you have discovered what is a good place to put your CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you running this from? I presume `www.mydomain.co.uk` is your server, and you're accessing it from an external client?

The main difference between `LOAD DATA` and `LOAD DATA LOCAL` is that the latter copies a file from the client to a temporary file in the server before continuing as an ordinary `LOAD DATA` command using the copied file; but *both the MySQL client and the server must have been built explicitly to enable it*. Since it is a potential security hole I would doubt very much if the server has been built that way.

Neither will accept an HTTP URL -- you need to specify a *path*. If you use `LOAD DATA` specifying just a bare filename then the server will look for it in the *default database directory*; or if it is a *relative* path with a directory component then the server treats it as being relative to the *data directory*; absolute paths are, of course, used literally.

How you get this to work depends on which server directories you can write to that the MySQL server can also read. There is little to be gained from `LOAD DATA LOCAL` as you can copy the CSV file yourself and have more control over it. The most likely candidate is the data directory, and you can discover where that is using

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir"
```

Then, if you put your file `myfile.csv` into this directory, you can use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "./myfile.csv" ...
```

to get the server to load the table from your file.

I hope this helps.